# reactjs iterating over an array and placing wrapper divs every nth element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the material ui grid system in react. I have a blob of json -- and wish to create a row every 4th element. So it wraps the container every 4th element -- also be able to control the nth element wrap - so to configure it if they ever wanted it every 2, 3 elements in a row.

something like this

```
let blogJson = [{
  "label" : "Dress up or down",
  "body" : "<p>xxx</p>",
  "image" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS1q3hgINIvT2lxrLXVMoDlHt92bjqmU9SPHQ&usqp=CAU"
},{
  "label" : "yyyyyyy",
  "body" : "<p>xxx</p>",
  "image" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS1q3hgINIvT2lxrLXVMoDlHt92bjqmU9SPHQ&usqp=CAU"
},{
  "label" : "nnnnnnnnnnn",
  "body" : "<p>xxx</p>",
  "image" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS1q3hgINIvT2lxrLXVMoDlHt92bjqmU9SPHQ&usqp=CAU"
},{
  "label" : "vvvvvvvvvv",
  "body" : "<p>xxx</p>",
  "image" : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS1q3hgINIvT2lxrLXVMoDlHt92bjqmU9SPHQ&usqp=CAU"
}]




      {            
        blogJson.map((item, j) => {
          return(
              
             {j % 4 === 0? '<Grid container spacing={1}>'}

             <Grid key={j}  item xs={12} sm={3}> 
              <Card className="blog-card">
                <CardContent>
                  <img src={item.image} alt="" />
                  <h3>{item.label}</h3>
                  {item.body}
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions>
                  <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                    <FavoriteIcon className="icon-heart" />
                  </IconButton>            
                </CardActions>
              </Card>
            </Grid>

            {j % 4 === 0? '</Grid>'}

          )
        })   
      }
```

Comment: Slice your array to 4-length pieces and map over those.

Comment: you have an example?

Comment: Added an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice the list into sub-lists and map over them.

Here's a neat `mapInSlices` helper for you.

```js
const posts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

function mapInSlices(array, sliceSize, sliceFunc) {
  const out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += sliceSize) {
    const slice = array.slice(i, i + sliceSize);
    out.push(sliceFunc(slice, i));
  }
  return out;
}

const App = () => (
  <main>
    {mapInSlices(posts, 4, (slice) => (
      <div>
        {slice.map((post) => (
          <span>{post}</span>
        ))}
      </div>
    ))}
  </main>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
}

span {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  background: cyan;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main id="root"></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to achieve this

```
{
  blogJson.map((item, j) => {
    return React.createElement(
      j % 4 === 0 ? Grid : React.Fragment,
      j % 4 === 0 ? { container: true, spacing: 1 } : {},
      <Grid key={j} item xs={12} sm={3}>
        <Card className="blog-card">
          <CardContent>
            <img src={item.image} alt="" />
            <h3>{item.label}</h3>
            {item.body}
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon className="icon-heart" />
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    )
  })
}
```

[image: Edit sparkling-wind-cw1pg]

Comment: @TheOldCounty check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-wind-cw1pg?file=/src/App.js)